# How to link the code in one jFrame with the code in another Jframe

Tags: java, user-interface

Im creating a GUI where a user creates an account and when he returns back to the main frame he can enter his account info and login.  To do this I so far have:

```
   //gets username and password from Login main frame
   String uName =txtfUserName.getText();
   String pass = txtfPassword.getText();    
   
  
   //signUpName && signUpPass are textfields from the second frame that stores the user's sign up account info. 
  //output I want but will not work
   if(uName.equals(signUpName)) && (pass.equals(signUpPass)){
       lblOutputMsg.setText("Access Granted");
   }else if(!uName.equals(signUpName)) || (!pass.equals(signUpPass)){
       lblOutputMsg.setText("Invalid");
    }
```

Second frame code

```
  String signUpName = txtfSetUpUName.getText();
  String signUpPass = txtfSetUpPass.getText(); 
    dispose();
    MainFrame firstFrame = new MainFrame();
    firstFrame.setVisible(true);
```

How would I refer back to the second Jframe to be able to use the code above? So that it takes the info the user made to create an account and sees if it matches with what is entered in the login screen.

EDIT:
What If instead of creating a second jFrame I just add a Panel within the main frame to ask for the user's credentials.  That way id be able to execute the code above.  The only problem is that the main frame will not close and it'll open up the second panel directly on top. Is there anyway I could close the main frame and just show the sign up panel alone and somehow return back to the mainframe?

Comment: The usual way is to inject the information you need by passing it in the constructor, or by using a `setX()` method to set the information in the object internal fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a common object to both the frames. Create a new class

```
class LoginInfo {

    Map<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<>();

    public boolean isValidCredentials(String username, String password) {
        return credentials.containsKey(username)&&credentials.get(username).equals(password);
    }
    
    public void addCredentials(String username, String password) {
        credentials.put(username, password);
    }
}
```

Then what you do is

1. Create LoginInfo instance
2. pass the same instance to both frames
3. use this instance to store and check credentials

> LoginInfo info = new LoginInfo();
> MainFrame firstFrame = new MainFrame(info);

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is an extra class called User. Then create an instance on this class and use these values for the different frames.

Do note that this removes the default constructor and if you want to use it you should re add it.

Look at this example I made:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Login {

    public static List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loginFrame();
    }

    public static void registerFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.add(panel);

        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        JTextField password = new JTextField();

        Dimension dim = new Dimension(50, 20);

        username.setPreferredSize(dim);
        password.setPreferredSize(dim);

        panel.add(username);
        panel.add(password);

        JButton submit = new JButton("submit");
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                userList.add(new User(username.getText(), password.getText()));
                frame.dispose();
                loginFrame();

            }
        });

        panel.add(submit);

        frame.pack();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void loginFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.add(panel);

        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        JTextField password = new JTextField();

        Dimension dim = new Dimension(50, 20);

        username.setPreferredSize(dim);
        password.setPreferredSize(dim);

        panel.add(username);
        panel.add(password);

        JButton submit = new JButton("login");
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                for(User user : userList) {
                    // can change to equalsIgnoreCase if you don't want the password or user name to be case sensitive
                    if(user.getUsername().equals(username.getText()) && user.getPassword().equals(password.getText())) {
                        System.out.println("Access Granted");
                        return;
                    }
                } System.out.println("Access Denied");

            }
        });
        
        JButton register = new JButton("register");
        register.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
                registerFrame();
                
            }
        });
        
        panel.add(submit);
        panel.add(register);
        
        frame.pack();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The User class

```
public class User {
    
    private String username;
    
    private String password;
    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Do keep in mind that this will not save the user once you stop the program the user will be discarded.